# get Shopify Report through API or embed through i frame

Tags: codeigniter, statistics, report, shopify

I have an app in codeigniter and want to get my product statistics throught API from shopify store, is there any way to get products statistics from shopify store through API? Or have any way to embed the products statistics chart to my app with ifram?

I consult these links [enter link description here](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/analytics-api#set-up).

Comment: What have you tried? Does your shop satisfy the requirements given in the link?

Comment: i tried analytic api https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/analytics-api#set-up when i embed code from https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/analytics-api#set-up  page my aplication redirect to shopify dashboard. My app shopify plane is Adnaced shopify that is the requirement  for reporting system.4